# Error while trying to update 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates

When I tried updating to Ubuntu 18.04, I got this:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Please help

Comment: Please clarify why you have precise (= Ubuntu 12.04) repos in 18.04?

Comment: @RoVo Thanks for mentioning about precise. I'm a new user and I don't know much about linux. Removing precise repos worked. Thanks a lot for helping!  :)

Comment: Glad I could help. You can answer your own question with the information how exactly you solved it so you might help others too :-)

Comment: Sure! Will do that. Thanks once again :) @RoVo

Answer (score 1):

I actually had wrong repository. Everything was fine once I removed it.

Thanks to @RoVo for helping me out :)

Comment: @abu_bua He can't accept a **comment**!  Read the comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the public key 40976EAF437D05B5 with:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5`

Comment: I actually had wrong repository. Everything was fine once I removed it. Btw, thanks for responding :)